# Prove if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^ \infty a_n$ converges, {$b_n$} is bounded & monotone, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^ \infty a_nb_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n$ converges, and {$b_n$} is bounded and monotone, then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_nb_n$ converges.

No, $a_n, b_n$ are not necessarily positive numbers.

I've been trying to use the Dirichlet's Test, but I have no way to show that $b_n$ goes to zero. If I switch $a_n$ and $b_n$ in Dirichlet's Test, I can show $a_n$ goes to zero, but then I'm having trouble showing that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \left\lvert a_{n+1}-a_{n}\right\rvert$ converges (because $a_n$ isn't necessarily monotone).

Comment: Use abel partial summation.

Comment: I have, that is what allowed me to show that the partial sums of  ∑anbn converge.  But, I still need to satisfy the other condition(s). It's these other conditions am having difficulty with.

Comment: Since {$b_n$} is bounded and monotone, it has a Max/Min (both cases are analogous). So let $M$ be a lower/upper bound (which is finite) for {$b_n$}, then $M\cdot\sum a_{n}$ converges... shouldn't be hard from there, or I could be missing something?

Comment: @mm8511 With this argument, you don't show convergence of the series, only that it's bounded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Outline:** Indeed, the key is use Dirichlet's test (a.k.a. [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) at its core) as you intended:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n &= \sum_{n=1}^N (A_n-A_{n-1}) b_n =
 A_Nb_N + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A_n b_n -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A_n b_{n+1} \\
&= A_Nb_N + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \underbrace{A_n}_{\text{bounded}} \underbrace{(b_n -b_{n+1})}_{\text{constant sign}}
\end{align}$$
where $A_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n$ and $A_0=0$.

Now, *this does not quite work:* the issue boils down to the fact that at the end of the day you cannot rely on $b_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$; since indeed *it is not necessarily true*. But you *need* this for the argument to go through.

To circumvent that, observe that $(b_n)_n$ is a bounded monotone sequence, and therefore is convergent. Let $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$ be its limit.

You can now define the sequence $(b^\prime_n)_n$ by $b^\prime_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} b_n-\ell$. This is a monotone bounded sequence *converging to $0$*, and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n b^\prime_n = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n - \ell \sum_{n=1}^N a_n.
$$
The second term is a convergent series by assumption on $(a_n)_n$, so showing convergence of the series $ \sum a_n b_n$ is equivalent to showing convergence of the series $\sum a_n b^\prime_n$. Apply your idea (Abel's summation) on the latter.

Comment: That's definitely what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad this was helpful... that's a nice question.

Comment: Can I conclude that OP's statement is a corollary of Dirichlet's test?

Comment: Sure, you can phrase it that way. @ChoMedit.