# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}$ converge and $\{b_n \}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}$ converge and $\{b_n \}$ is monotone and bounded,  show that 
 $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n b_n}$ converge.

Comment: I must prove it

Comment: Have you tried a direct comparison?

Comment: I don't know how to start the proof

Comment: To show a series is convergent, what tools do you have?

Comment: Wlog the $b_n$ are positive and decreasing to $0$, then apply Abel's inequality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^ \infty a_n$ converges, {$b_n$} is bounded & monotone, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^ \infty a_nb_n$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641119/prove-if-sum-limits-n-1-infty-a-n-converges-b-n-is-bounded-monoton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write using partial sums $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$, starting with $s_0=0$. Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^∞ a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^∞(s_n-s_{n-1})b_n
=\sum_{n=1}^∞ s_n(b_n-b_{n+1})
$$
so that now you have inside the series the product of a converging, thus bounded sequence and the terms of an absolutely convergent series.